# Does [ascii-art] mean only ASCII?

Tags: discussion, tags

I'm looking at the [ascii-art](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art) excerpt, which says:

> ASCII Art is a graphic design technique that uses 93 of the 128 printable ACSII characters to create images.

Whilst this is almost true (it uses the 93 printable/space characters of the 128-character ASCII set), I believe the term is also used for character art using different character sets (mostly supersets of ASCII).

Would I be justified in re-writing this so that it allows character-art in general?

Comment: Are you thinking of things like this? ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ The center character is not ascii, but we are making an old-school emoji out of it.

Comment: "Old-school emoji" is usually spelt "emoticon", but yes, I'm thinking of things like that, plus Unicode box-drawing characters, and anything else that makes pictures, charts or diagrams using non-ASCII characters.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's approach this part by part.

> Does [ascii-art] mean only ASCII?

Yes, otherwise it should be tagged [character-art](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/character-art) or similar.

> Whilst this is almost true

If you think a tag wiki needs improvement, please improve it.

> Would I be justified in re-writing this so that it allows character-art in general?

If the tag was named [character-art](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/character-art) instead of [ascii-art], that would've been a great idea.

I'd propose the following:

- Create a new tag [character-art](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/character-art).
- Synonimize [ascii-art](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art) to [character-art](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/character-art) or half the users will stick the wrong tag on the question. ASCII art is a wide-spread (and often mis-used IMO) name. People will look for the tag and people will use both tags if we don't somehow smash them together.
- Put your suggested text in the [character-art](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/character-art) description.

Either that, or simply rename [ascii-art](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art) to [character-art](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/character-art), edit the tag description as suggested afterwards. [ascii-art](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art) isn't used much as a tag after all and it's arguable it even needs it's own tag. Should the tag ever be created again we'll cross that bridge when we come to it.

I'm ambivalent about which route is better.

Comment: I agree with this response, but don't use [tag:formatting]. I believe an alias from [tag:ascii-art] to a new tag [tag:character-art] would be fine. Go ahead and create the tag while you can still get there first, Toby

Comment: I didn't even realise there was [tag:character-art] - it doesn't seem very busy!

Comment: @TobySpeight It doesn't exist (yet). But you can link [tag:tags] to [tag:pretty-much-anything] and the system will put you on it's page regardless. Even if the tag doesn't exist.

Comment: @TobySpeight  Note that you create a tag by finding a question where it is about character-art rather than specifically ascii-art and changing from ascii-art to character-art.  The system creates tags when they are first used.  If none of the existing questions are actually about non-ASCII character art, this change may be premature.  Of course, you could always write an appropriate program and ask about it.